# Is 5Ghz signal overlap on channel 149 a concern?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router

I have a dual band ATT Default Gateway router. It offers 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz. There are two other routers also on 5Ghz on channel 149. Is this a concern for interference or jamming? If so, how and what can I choose for a different channel in 5Ghz?

Comment: 5Ghz is pretty short range compared to 2.4Ghz... Assuming this is in a residential setting it may or may not cause some interference, but with it's shorter range it is generally less of a concern than 2.4Ghz congestion. If you log into your routers administration interface, there is likely a place you can specify the channel(s) used, or in many wireless routers a reset of the device will cause it to rescan the area and select a different channel automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how close the neighboring routers are on ch 149 it could be a concern. It is probably not going to totally jam your network, but it will reduce throughput and add latency because of packet loss / re-transmission.

you can use something like WiFi analyzer, or Wiggle Wifi from the play store if you have an android. (and a supported WiFi chip-set in the phone). I believe there is also a sister version of Wiggle Wifi for IOS.

This will allow you to survey the local radio environment and choose a channel no one is using, (hopefully) Plus in a worst case scenario choose the channel with the least amount of adjacent neighborhood routers

If you aren't sure of the channel lingo, or wireless tech in general, articles [like this](https://www.ekahau.com/blog/2019/04/18/channel-planning-best-practices-for-better-wi-fi/) will show you pretty much everything you need to know.